# How to photograph a paper-boat in the river?

Tags: composition, product-photography, gifts

I have this idea of taking photo of a handmade boat and show it as it is waving in a river!...
Here is a normal photo of the boat itself:

[image]

My camera is a semi-professional Canon!
Ideas about the angle, background, the river material and how to make it seem wavy or even suggested applications, effects would be appreciated..... :)

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad to be answerable. You could get a collection of possible ideas, but there's no way one can really be an answer. I suggest narrowing your goals (what do you want to show or express with the boat in the river?), and also trying some things and asking specifically about aspects you had trouble with (for example, the part about depicting waves).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right the question might bring lots of ideas, I just wanted to capture a fantasy scene with this boat and gift it to a friend (who actually made this boat); I thought capturing it in this scene might seem nice! But I had difficulty to implement what was in my mind.

Comment: @Hatef Questions on Stack Exchange _shouldn't_ 'bring lots of ideas', they are meant to have factual answers not fanciful ones

Comment: Yes I understand. Thanks for your comment. @ClaraOnager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to do it entirely practically (in real life) or is post production work a possibility.  The easiest way to do it (since it needs to sit in the water) is to place the boat in to a photo of an actual river in Photoshop or GIMP.

Alternately, on the practical side, you could float it in a filled section of dark colored rain gutter or similar, line it up carefully with the angle of a river in the background and take a photo.  If you take it with a shallow enough depth of field, it may conceal the edges of the water container sufficiently (or a little touch up in Photoshop could help remove them.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to photograph the boat in a real river then one problem is that the boat will go downstream faster then you can setup. Solve this by attaching a nylon fishing line to the boat and anchoring it upstream. Done carefully the line will be invisible or under the water.